# How would you use index notation to prove this identity?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

How would you use index notation to prove that $\underline{\nabla} \cdot (\underline{u} \times \underline{v})=(\underline{\nabla} \times \underline{u}) \cdot \underline{v}-(\underline{\nabla} \times \underline{v}) \cdot \underline{u}$?

My attempt is shown in the image below, but there is clearly a flaw in my workings as it does not give the required result:

[image: attempt]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you have $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\varepsilon_{ijk}u_jv_k), $$ you only wrote one term instead of two. Applying the product rule: $$ \varepsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}v_k+\varepsilon_{ijk}u_j\frac{\partial v_k}{\partial x_i}=(\mathbf{\nabla}\times u)_kv_k-\varepsilon_{ikj}\frac{\partial v_k}{\partial x_i}u_j=(\mathbf{\nabla}\times u)_kv_k-(\mathbf{\nabla}\times v)_ju_j= $$ $$ =(\mathbf{\nabla}\times u)\cdot v-(\mathbf{\nabla}\times v)\cdot u. $$

Comment: But isn't $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ a term in the equation (i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}, \dots , \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n}})$), rather than an operation?

Comment: @user2910074 $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is the $i$-th component of the list you just listed. However, it is also a differential operator, thus it has the derivation property.